# Magento Attribute option Value is not showing in admin side

Tags: magento

I have Multistore Magento Store. I had created some of the custom attributes from Manage Attribute which is located here catalog->attributes->Manage Attribute

I have one multi select custom attribute which is visible for both main default store and and one other store.

It is created successfully with some of the option value in it and also assigned it to attribute set.

But the Problem is when I click on any particular product and go through that attribute I didn't find any value in that attribute for selection purpose.

I didn't find any solutions regarding that. Is anybody having solution regarding this?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that there happens change attribute type?

If you create an attribute as `dropdown` with `backend_type` `varchar` and then change it to `int` then there remains some records in table `catalog_entity_varchar`. Those data prevents displaying value of attribute in backend. Reason is that Magneto looks first to table `catalog_entity_varchar` where found label of option instead of id of option. If it pushes a label into model then HTML select on backend form does not fit that value because it expects id of option but it get label of option.

Comment: I have similar situation in M2. I had a attribute with input field, changed it to dropdown in database table(eav_attribute). since then all the old records are not saving dropdown values. what is the possible solution for this....should i change any thing else.

Answer (score -1):

This value should be set to 'YES' in catalog->attributes->Manage Attribute
Frontend Properties >Visible on Product View Page on Front-end > YES.

Comment: Hello thnx for reply but i don't want it to show in front i just want to show the default value in backend which is not showing right now! as you told is not the issue in my case. i know if i want to show Attribute in front i have to do what you told but i want to show in admin which is not showing right now! getting

Comment: Sorry I think I understand what you are saying. Just select the attribute, then under 'Attribute Information' > Manage Label / Options 

Create your options and select 'Is Default' for whichever you want it to to be default.

Comment: Hi Darshan, sorry for the trouble. My final suggestion is this link on Magento website which talks about default values for multi select. Hope it works out. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/index